# find command + remove older directories according to directory time stamp

Tags: linux, find

I want to delete directories that older than 180 days

for example directories that older than 180 days:

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Oct  1  2009 nis
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Nov  4  2012 pkgs
```

I use this command:

```
find /var/tmp  -depth -mindepth 1 -type d -ctime +180  -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

After I run the find command , I see that the older directories are still exist

Please advice what wrong with my find command?

```
[root@vm1 /var/tmp]# ls -ltr
total 20
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Oct  1  2009 nis
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Nov  4  2012 pkgs
drwxr-x--- 2 root root 4096 Dec  3 08:24 1
drwxr-x--- 2 root root 4096 Dec  3 08:41 2
drwxr-x--- 2 root root 4096 Dec  3 08:41 3

[root@vm1 /var/tmp]# find /var/tmp  -depth -mindepth 1 -type d -ctime +180  -exec rm -rf {} \;

[root@vm1 /var/tmp]# ls -ltr
total 20
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Oct  1  2009 nis
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Nov  4  2012 pkgs
drwxr-x--- 2 root root 4096 Dec  3 08:24 1
drwxr-x--- 2 root root 4096 Dec  3 08:41 2
drwxr-x--- 2 root root 4096 Dec  3 08:41 3
```

I also try this ( but not remove the old dir ) the -mtime only change the date of the old dir to the current date

```
   find /var/tmp  -depth -mindepth 1 -type d -mtime +180  -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

Answer (score 1):

-t     sort by modification time

try

```
find /var/tmp  -depth -mindepth 1 -type d -mtime +180  -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

Update : delete options depth and mindepth

Comment: its not delete the old dir, ots only update the old dir to the curent day date - why?

Comment: I need the depth and mindepth because if they not defined then it will  dlete also the tmp dir under /var

Comment: -atime (last access) last access time changed - see Update  delete options depth and mindepth

Comment: I cant to delete the option - depth and mindepth ( as I said if I will update the find without these option then it will remocve the tmp dir under /var )

Comment: do you that I will change the -mtime to -atime ?

Comment: any IDEA what NEED TO do next?

Comment: Give us the output of the command : find /var/tmp -type d -mtime +180

Comment: I get the list of nis and pkgs ( after I copy them to /var/tmp ) again with the old date

Comment: so find /var/tmp  -type d -mtime +180  -exec rm -rf {} \; should be ok

Comment: test with i interactive) option rm -rfi